# Inserting calculated data from a specific row in a table and move it into a specific row in another table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am stuck at moving a data from a table into another table in sql server for days now (I'm still new). So, if  I calculate a sum of a data from a specific row in column (eg: sum of product a) of a table, how do I move the calculated data to another specific row in a column with the same product but in another table?

Comment: With an `INSERT`/`UPDATE` depending on if the row already exists or not.

Comment: Please share more details such as your table structures, sample data, expected output etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on whether the product (I used an `id` column in my sample data) already exists in the target table you will need one of the approaches below.

**Sample data**

```
-- source table
create table tblValues
(
  id int,
  value int
);

insert into tblValues (id, value) values
(100, 1),
(100, 2),
(100, 3),
(200, 4),
(200, 5),
(200, 6),
(300, 7);

-- target table
create table tblSums
(
  id int,
  sumValue int
);
```

**Solution 1**

```
insert into tblSums (id, sumValue)
select v.id, sum(v.value) as idSum
from tblValues v
group by v.id;

select * from tblSums; --> sums for id 100 / 200 / 300
```

**Sample data changes**

```
-- reset
truncate table tblSums;

-- populate id column of tblSums
insert into tblSums (id) values
(100),
(200);
```

**Solution 2**

```
update s
set s.sumValue = v2.sumValue
from tblSums s
cross apply ( select sum(v.value) as sumValue
              from tblValues v
              where v.id = s.id
              group by v.id ) v2;

select * from tblSums; --> sums for id 100 / 200
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ee85d068375a8d2151da9ff180f85e63) to see the whole thing in action.